# Strange code error

Tags: c++, c

This is regarding the [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/981162/c-c-identify-the-digits-in-a-given-number) which I posted earlier today. I made the program to identify and print the digits of a given number. The program runs fine when I use 1, 2, 4 digits (I made 4 max), but when I input a 3-digit number, it prints the numbers wrong and ends abruptly. Help me out..

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <digits.h>
int getDigit(long);
int main()
{
  int ctr, digits, dig, multiNo, number;
  printf("Enter the number(4 digits max): ");
  scanf("%d", &number);
  printf("\n");
  digits = getDigit(number);
  if (digits == 1)
     printf("%d\n", number);
  else              
  {
    multiNo = pow(10, (digits-1));
    ctr = 1;
    dig = (number/multiNo);
    printf("%d ", dig);    
    while (ctr < digits)  
    {     
      number %= multiNo;
      multiNo/= 10;
      dig = (number/multiNo);
      printf("%d ", dig);
      ctr++;
    }
  }
  printf("\n\n");
  system("PAUSE");
  return 0;
}

int getDigit(long num)
{
  long divider = 10; 
  int digit, i;
  for (i=1; i<=9; i++)
  {
    digit = (num/divider);
    if (digit == 0)
      break;
    else
      divider *= 10;
  }
  return i;
}
```

Sorry, I'm using a phone to browse internet, so unable to format..

Comment: Could you post the getDigit(int) function anyway, so that this code can compile and run? It looks like that function is doing getNumberOfDigits(int), but we can't be entirely sure.

Comment: For which input number it is giving error. It is working fine for me even with getDigit() impl.

Comment: For every 3 digit number!! Also check the getDigit function, i've included it..

Answer (score 2):

Apparently code looks fine. Please check the return value of `getDigit(number);`.

I just hard coded as `digits = 3/*getDigit(number)*/;` and the code was printing proper values for 3 digit number.

Answer (score 1):

Since I dont have your getDigit() function I just let my version return 3, so I can test a 3 digit number and it works fine. My guess is that your getDigit() is messed up.

You program works just fine.

Comment: Talk about orange bar of death and exact same answer =/

Answer (score 0):

changing the top of main to:

```
//  printf("Enter the number(4 digits max): ");
//  scanf("%d", &number);
for(int x=1;x<10000;x++){
    number=x;
```

and a } at the bottom seems to work for me for any length of number.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me but you need to clarify the type you are passing for the first parameter to 'pow' i.e.

```
multiNo = pow((double)10, (digits-1));
```

Answer (score 0):

Simpler logic:

```
void print_digits(unsigned number) {
    unsigned next = number / 10;
    if ( next ) {
        print_digits( next );
    }

    printf( "-%d-", number % 10 );
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As a lazy programmer, I would print the digits this way:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  char Digits[ 129 ];
  printf( "Enter digits: " );
  gets( Digits );
  if( strlen( Digits ) < 1 )
  {
     printf( "\nNo digits!" );
     system( "PAUSE" );
     return 0;
  }
  printf( "Number of digits: %d\n\n", strlen( Digits ) );
  for( int Loop = 0; Loop < strlen( Digits ); Loop++ )
     printf( "Digit %d: %d\n", Loop, Digits[ Loop ] );
  system( "PAUSE" );
  return 0;
}
```