# How to print digit by digit of a number?

Tags: c, digits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Identify the digits in a given number.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/981162/identify-the-digits-in-a-given-number)

I need to print each digit of number without convert it to string. It's possible? 
For example:

```
int n = 1234;
int x;

while( ?? ) {
  x = ??
  printf("%d\n", x); 
}
```

it prints:

```
1
2
3
4
```

I have no idea how to do this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can do it! look up  modulo

Comment: Very basic question that smells like homework.

Comment: but anyway, the idea was to do this without converting to a string

Comment: @Jack - You need to understand how to accomplish it.. someone else doing it won't help. I really suggest P&P - paper pencil

Answer (score 3):

Unless you tell me this isn't homework, I won't give the full answer.

Note that `x / 10` gives you `x` stripped of the last digit.  So `123 / 10 = 12`, `45 / 10 = 4`, etc.

And note that `x % 10` gives you the last digit of `x`.  So `123 % 10 = 3`, `45 % 10 = 5`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

This actually touches on number theory / mathematical methods. You can write a number 1234, for example, as `1x10^3 + 2x10^2 + 3x10^1 + 4x10^0`. Now think about how you can use `%` (mod) and `/` (integer division) to extract each digit.

Answer (score 2):

If you know the maximum number of digits, you can do it using / and %

so for instance, if you want to find the thousands place, the answer is

```
num =...
int thousands = (num / 1000) % 10
```

you can actually do this in a loop